# fscanf() with varying inputs?

Tags: c

I'm new to C and am trying to use `fscanf` to read from lines of a file of varying lengths

There are 3 different lines that can be read from the file, namely:

```
string
string char
string char char
```

I have this:

```
char elem1;
char elem2;
char *str;

while(fscanf(file, %s%c%c, str, &elem1, &elem2) == 3) {
    ...do stuff
}
```

So obviously this is fine when I get all 3 expected arguments, but if the line just contained a string then the first two characters of the string on the next line would be assigned to elem1 and 2.

How can I account for that?

Answer (score 3):

You should read the entire line and the use `strtok` to get the words on the line.

Edit: See the comment discussion for the benefit of using `strtok_r` instead of `strtok`.

Comment: You should never use `strtok`.  If you must, use `strtok_r`.

Comment: The `strtok()` function uses a static buffer while parsing, so it's not thread safe.  Use `strtok_r()` if this matters to you.

Comment: It is ***far worse*** than a thread-safety issue.  Because of its internal state, `strtok` is not even safe within a single callstack.

Comment: Can you please give me an example or point me to some place where to learn about this? I lived my entire live so far thinking wrongly about this subject.

Comment: http://ideone.com/VU6Eue   Example app.  It is a basic single threaded app.  Given data like:  `"WA Seattle SEA;OR Portland PDX;NY NewYork LGA;FL Miami MIA"` parse to separate by the `;`, then parse out each individual element.  In my example: Stage1 works, Stage2 works, but if you combine them in Stage3, it does not work.  Definitely worth 15 minutes of time to trace through this program.

Comment: Ah, now I understand what you're referring to. Thanks. I used to solve this kind of problems by using multiple passes through the input :)

Comment: Of course, it can be solved by redesigning the software.  But what if you code one piece using `strtok`, and another developer, in a different corporate division, writes another piece using `strtok`?  You may not even know about each other.  Your software will work perfectly when tested separately, and break when integrated into a larger program.   `strtok` is fundamentally broken, and can never be safely used.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `fgets` to read in a line at a time, then `sscanf` to look through just that line for the 1, 2, or 3 items.

```
char elem1; char elem2; char str[1000]; char line[1000];

while(fgets(line, 1000, file) != NULL) {
    switch(sscanf(line, "%s %c %c", str, &elem1, &elem2)) {
        case 3: /* str, elem1, elem2 are valid */
            break;
        case 2: /* str and elem1 are valid */
            break;
        case 1: /* str is valid */
            break;
    }
}
```